# On what dates do the U.S. and Canada release their respective federal budgets?

Tags: united-states, canada, budget, monetary-policy

What is the date on which the U.S. officially announces its budget? What is the date for Canada? I want to know the dates because I would like to go back to historical charts and see if the stock market made sharp moves immediately following budget announcement.

Also is the fiscal policy and monetary policy announced with the budget or are they announced separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US there is no set date.

- In the US the president and his staff release their budget request in February or later.
- Congress then takes each agency budget resolution and modifies it and votes on them. It can take several rounds if the two houses don't agree. Each agency resolution moves at a different speed though the process.
- Then they have to pass appropriations bills that actually fund the individual projects within each agency.

If all goes well there are multiple dates of importance. If it doesn't go well the budget process also may include continuing resolutions, shutdowns, and sequestrations.

Comment: There is an implicit hard deadline of September 30 for the U.S. gov't to approve an operating budget for the next year, as the U.S. fiscal year begins in Q4 of the calendar year. However, Mhoran's right; no set date for the President or anyone else to make a budget proposal public, or for Congress to approve any given proposal.

Answer (score 3):

Canada does not have a set date on which a (Federal) budget plan is unveiled. In 2011 it was June 6th. In 2012 it was March 29th and in 2013 it was 21st March.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no firm date requirement. The fiscal year for the US Federal Government starts on October 01, but if my memory serves me right, last time a budget was approved before the fiscal year started was during the Clinton administration.

Comment: By some measures [the last time a budget was approved *at all* was during the Clinton administration.](http://www.policymic.com/articles/65885/america-hasn-t-had-a-budget-for-over-three-years-so-don-t-expect-one-anytime-soon)